# Find a matching value in an array and it's count

Tags: arrays, matlab

Just a quick one. I need to find a matching certain value in an array and retrieve the location/order of the matching value.

Edited according to Matt's answer but still not working:

```
 l = min (points(2:2:end));
 Y = find((points(2:2:end))==l);
 count=numel(Y);
```

results:

```
  count = 1
  l = 205
```

correct result given below example should be:

```
 result = 4
```

Example to clarify:

my array is [114 205 137 205 144 204]. assume the matching value is 205; location or order in this case should be 4. That's it, 4 is all what I want.

Comment: points(2:2:end) is a condition as I don't want Y to be matched to the other values in the array.

Comment: your title asks for the count, your question asks for the location, and you code is only counting... do you need the location or just the count?

Comment: location which could be known by a counter!

Comment: @Brig That doesn't make any sense. A counter does not give you a location.

Comment: After tirelessly searching, I found a duplicate.  It's a wonder because I've answered this kind of question countless times... yet I couldn't find a suitable question/answer in my history.  StackOverflow's search engine needs to be improved.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the help. Sorry none of this will work. I need the location (in other words the order) of the matching value.

Comment: What do you mean by "order"?? You have a 2D array.  Which order are you referring to?

Comment: my array is [114
   205
   137
   205
   144
   204]. assume the matching value is 144; location or order in this case should be 4. That's it, 4 is all what I want.

Comment: The value is in the 5th position of that array.  Are you to say that you want to find the position subtracted by 1?

Comment: Sorry yes the 5th! My bad. No it's fine I can do (x-1) by myself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `find` to get the indexes/positions and use `numel` to get the count. Because you are **skipping** elements you need to multiply the result of `find` with 2.

```
points = [114 205 137 205 144 204 222 204];

l     = min(points(2:2:end))
Y     = 2 * find(points(2:2:end)==l) % Y is the position in the original array
count = numel(Y)
```

Outputs:

```
l =
   204
Y =
     6     8
count =
     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. I'm assuming that points is a row vector but this method can be easily extended to arrays of any shape

```
>> points = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1];
>> y = find(points == 1)

y = 

     1     6     11

>> length(y)

ans =

     3

>>
```

`y` contains the indices of the points satisfying the condition. See the documentation for `find` here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Comment: You are not actually assigning `Y`.

Comment: @Matt - Edited so that the code is assigning to `y`.

Comment: this doesn't do it either :(